# Percentage with keyframes broke seconds

Tags: css, animation

This code with pixels work perfect but with % seconds change.

Can you help me to find a solution?
Thank you for all your help on this question.

I need to write something... then I write this.

```css
/* .qt-quotes */
.qt-quotes {
  width: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, grey 10px, white 0);
  animation: qt-qotes-height 1s normal both, qt-qotes-width 1s normal 1s both, qt-qotes-shadow 1s 2s normal both;
}

.qt-quotes p {
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 2.5px 20px;
  animation: qt-qotes-text 1s 2s normal both;
}

@keyframes qt-qotes-height {
  from{max-height: 0;}
  to{max-height: 100%;}
}

@keyframes qt-qotes-width {
  from{max-width: 10px;}
  to{max-width: 100%;}
}

@keyframes qt-qotes-text {
  from{visibility: hidden;; opacity: 0;}
  to{visibility: visible; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes qt-qotes-shadow {
  from {box-shadow: none;}
  to {box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px grey;}
}

/* .qt-not-copyable */

.qt-not-copyable {
 user-select: none;
}
```

```html
   <div class="qt-quotes qt-not-copyable">
    <p><i>"This isn't a second..."</i></p>
      <p>idk</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: which one of the animation? it's seems a second for me ..

Comment: Its not a second. To seems a second you have to put 10s in the first and 5s in the second. You see is not 1s because the second animation start with perfect 1s after the first.